# While Updating the category in existing category, should not be displayed in dropdown box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

Iam trying to create a dropdown box for blog category using php and while editing the category form it should not be display the existing category name which i need to update in category form.

Example i have a product electronics under that category i have laptop and mobile , if i update mobile in dropdown box mobile option should not be displayed Thanks in advance

[The form look like this now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxA4t.png)

[The second form in which i highlighten **"laptop"** Keyword , while editing it should not be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3fNF.png)

```
       <select name="category" class="field" style="width:160px" >
       <option value="0">Select</option>
        {var name='cat_ops'}
       </select>

      if ($_GET['action'] == 'edit' && $_GET['id']) {
       $sel_cat =$cate_id ;
      } else {
      $sel_cat = "";
      }
      construct_cat_ops($sel_cat);
     $tmpl->setvar('cat_ops', $cat_ops);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      if ($_POST['update'] && $_POST['hid_id']) {
      if($brand==$categoryname){
         $msg = "Parent category cannot be same";
         $tmpl->setvar('msg_err', $msg);
       }else{
      $db->query("Update `blog_category` set`name`='$brand',`parent`='$category' where id='" . $_POST['hid_id'] . "'");
      $msg = "Blog category Updated Successfully";
      $tmpl->setvar('msg_ok', $msg);
      $tmpl->setvar('name', $brand);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should be, anyway i dont know php code is in separate file and html/tpl code in separate file.

```
if ($_GET['action'] == 'edit' && $_GET['id']) {
       $sel_cat =$cate_id ;
      } else {
      $sel_cat = "";
      }
      construct_cat_ops($sel_cat);
     $tmpl->setvar('cat_ops', $cat_ops);

<select name="category" class="field" style="width:160px" >
       <option value="0">Select</option>
        {var name='cat_ops'}
       </select>
```

Comment: Hi, yes html code is in seperate file and php is in seperate file

Comment: Hiee. are you using smarty?

Comment: ohh dear, smarty is template framwork of php and phpstrome is editor :D

Comment: your code looks like you are using smarty as template framework

Comment: did you get solution for this?

Comment: No dint got Sir, even a pop message is also fine.

Comment: Sir i resolved the problem, i just gave` if( $name == $ category )` i checked the condition then gave popup message. Thanks for your support.